# saved passwords in google chrome deleted

Tags: chrome-for-android

I was using google chrome browser since last 2 years on my laptops and myu phone. I had more than 100 passwords saved in my google chrome account which was syncing well across my devices. However today when I checked almost all of the passwords have  deleted from this sync account and only 5 passwords are there remaining. What caused this problem? Is there any way to recover this deleted passwords?

Comment: Have you checked the passwords on https://passwords.google.com/? Are you using multiple/the same Google accounts?

Comment: HI,  yes I have checked this. Even here I have only 4 passwords saved.

Comment: I'm afraid that's a bigger issue since the source sync data only has 4 passwords. Unless you're really sure that you are already looking at the correct Google account, someone might have accessed this page and deleted your passwords, then got synced to all devices already. In addition that this is not an Android issue anymore, I don't think there's anything that an end-user can do to undo this. You possibly need to contact Google directly about this.